# Return reference to argument object

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if this is correct even though I think it should be.

```
std::string &MyClass::MyFunc(std::string &buffer, int nValue)
{
    ... do something to buffer ...

    return buffer;
}
```

When I return the reference to the object that was passed in, I assume that this is valid, because the lifetime is in the parent scope.
Or could it be that the compiler returns a reference to some internal state?

Reason why I want to use this is, so that I don't need to allocate an object inside the function, but can still use the object in an nested function call.

i.e.:

```
std::string v;
int value;

doSomething(MyFunc(v, value));
```

Comment: Yes that is valid and will work fine.

Comment: @CoryKramer: Arghargharghargharghargh y u answer in comments ffs

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't feel that what I wrote was sufficient for an answer. For a full-blown answer, I would generally elaborate much further than just "yes that's fine", but I was a bit lazy this morning :)

Comment: @CoryKramer: Then may I humbly suggest leaving it to the answerers? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's completely ok.

In fact, it it also what is done when overloading out-of-class stream operators, assignment operators, increment/decrement, etc.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T const&)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right! I should have thought of this, then I could have looked it up myself. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is fine.

You only get a dangling reference if you return a reference to something which is then destroyed, such as local variable in a function.

You are returning a reference to an argument, which is fine so long as whatever it references is not destroyed by something else.

This is exactly how you should implement the kind of chaining you desire.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct.

Passing reference like this is just like passing a normal pointer.